# Handling no records found in delete statement with returning json_build_object in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm having some trouble with a postgres function where I'm deleting a row and returning a json_build_object where the row doesn't exist.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DeleteXJSON(
    in_x_id BIGINT)
    RETURNS SETOF JSON AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    ref_json_data   JSON;
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM xtable WHERE x_id = in_x_id
        RETURNING json_build_object('x_id', x_id) INTO ref_json_data;
    RETURN QUERY (select ref_json_data);
  END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

This works fine when it finds the row to delete but when no row is found it ends up returning 1 row instead of expectd 0 rows.

I've simplified the json_build_object fields as there are actually a dozen fields I return inside of there.  How do I handle this appropriately so 0 rows return when it doesn't exist?  If there's a way better way to deal with this, let me know.

### Update #1:

I fixed the bogus END IF.  However, if I run this through psql:

```
select * from deletexjson(1);
```

I get the following:

```
 deletecampjson 
 ----------------

 (1 row)
```

Comment: Recheck your code; you have an `END IF` without an opening `IF`.

Comment: (After deleting you `END IF;`) works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b9e44fad5eff30fef16feb3653f86973

Comment: just a general note on style, object names (tables, views, functions, triggers, etc.) in postgresql are case insensitive _unless enclosed in double-quotes_, un-quoted names get implicitly converted to lower case. The style most often seen in postgresql is unquoted lowercase with underscores.

Comment: Updated my question to fix the bogus END IF as noted.  Sorry about that.  I'm going to try the answer below and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error, as pointed out by [eurotrash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3733070/eurotrash) and [S-Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3984221/s-man) is the stray `END IF`.

However, as currently stated, there isn't a need to store the deleted row's json into `ref_json_data`. Nor are there any procedural elements. That is, you can write a SQL function instead of a PLPGSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deletexjson (xid BIGINT)
    RETURNS SETOF JSON AS 
    $$
        DELETE FROM xtable WHERE x_id = xid
            RETURNING JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('x_id', x_id, 'x_rand', x_rand);
    $$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

for a shorter expression (and possibly faster evaluation) of the same logic.

Comment: This fixed the problem and simplified the logic.  Perfect!  Thank you.